# error: called object type 'double' is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c

So I am new to C and was doing this project and keep running into this error when trying to compile it,

ERROR:

```
sphere.c:25:22: error: called object type 'double' is not a function or function pointer
```

CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

  double radius, surfArea, volume;

  printf("Enter the radius of a sphere: /n");
  scanf("%lf", & radius);

  if(radius <= 0){

    printf("Invalid entry");
      exit(1);
  }
  surfArea = M_PI*4.00*(pow(radius, 2));
  volume = (4/3)*M_PI(pow(radius, 3));        //line 25

  printf("Entererd radius is: %f", & radius);
  printf("The surface area is: %f", & surfArea);
  printf("The volume is: %f", & volume);

  return (0);
}
```

edit: Thanks everyone I got it working!

Comment: `printf` and `scanf` don't work the same. The later takes the address of a variable to store something in it, thus the `&` operator. `printf` uses the values, so there should be no `&`. Please watch that code that you put in your questions compiles without errors or warnings with the highest warning level of your compiler switched on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
volume = (4/3)*M_PI(pow(radius, 3)); 
                   ^
```

There is a missing operator here (probably a `*`).

Note that `4/3` is an integer division, if you want a floating point division you need one of the operand to be of a floating point type, e.g., `4 / 3.0`.

**EDIT:** Well I noticed there are many other errors in your code, I let you fix them.